# Format dynamically created Radio buttons in Columns in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I am creating radio buttons programatically for each element in an array/list and place them in a windows form.

Right now every new radio button is place under the previous one. How can i manage to start a new column after e.g. 4/5 radio buttons? The new column should appear on the right side of the previous radio-buttons.

This is my code so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < startShapes.Count; i++)
{
    RadioButton rdb = new RadioButton();
    rdb.Text = startShapes.Values.ElementAt(i).Equals("") ? startShapes.Keys.ElementAt(i) : startShapes.Values.ElementAt(i);
    rdb.Size = new Size(100, 30);
    this.Controls.Add(rdb);
    rdb.Location = new Point(45, 70 + 35 * i);
    rdb.CheckedChanged += (s, ee) =>
    {
        var r = s as RadioButton;
        if (r.Checked)
            this.selectedString = r.Text;
    };
}
```

Comment: Start new column where? Why don't you share what you have done till now?

Comment: Increase the Left value of the next radio buttons?

Comment: @Abhishek post is updated!

Comment: Add your RadioButtons to a FlowLayoutPanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using TableLayoutPanel?

```
        Dictionary<string, string> startShapes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
            startShapes.Add("Shape " +i, "Shape " +i);
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount= 0;
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1;

        foreach (var kvp in startShapes)
        {
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
            tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
            RadioButton rdb = new RadioButton();
            rdb.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value) ? kvp.Key : kvp.Value;
            rdb.Size = new Size(100, 30);
            rdb.CheckedChanged += (s, ee) =>
            {
                var r = s as RadioButton;
                if (r.Checked)
                    this.selectedString = r.Text;
            };
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(rdb, col, row);
            row++;
            if (row == 5)
            {
                col++;
                row = 0;
                tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
                tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount++;
            }
        }
```

And if you really need your solution:

```
int left = 45;
int idx = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < startShapes.Count; i++)
{
    RadioButton rdb = new RadioButton();
    rdb.Text = startShapes.Values.ElementAt(i).Equals("") ? startShapes.Keys.ElementAt(i) : startShapes.Values.ElementAt(i);
    rdb.Size = new Size(100, 30);
    this.Controls.Add(rdb);
    rdb.Location = new Point(left, 70 + 35 * idx++);
    if (idx == 5)
    {
        idx = 0; // reset row
        left += rdb.Width + 5; // move to next column
    }
    rdb.CheckedChanged += (s, ee) =>
    {
        var r = s as RadioButton;
        if (r.Checked)
            this.selectedString = r.Text;
    };
}
```